How to plot a mean line on kdeplot for each variable
I would like to visualize the mean and percentiles for each variable plotted on kdeplot
The code provided here "kdeplot showing mean and quartiles" does draw the mean and percentiles on the plot, but I would like to do so for a plot that has several variables such as the one displayed by the code below.
sns.kdeplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", hue="species", multiple="stack");

In otherwords, is there a way to obtain the transformed flipper_length_mm data used in generating the plot for each of the 3 species?

To get the values that created each of the curves, you can extract the rows for the species (e.g. x = penguins[penguins['species'] == 'Adelie']). To get the name of the species in the correct order, you could extract their names from the legend (in reverse order, as seaborn first plots the last one).
As the values can contain NaNs, np.nanmean() calculates the mean ignoring those. To account for the stacked kde curves, you can store the previous curve and only fill between the previous and the current curve.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
ax = sns.kdeplot(data=penguins, x='flipper_length_mm', hue='species', multiple='stack', fill=False)

prev_ys = 0
for kdeline, legend_text in zip(ax.lines, ax.legend_.texts[::-1]):
    x = penguins[penguins['species'] == legend_text.get_text()]['flipper_length_mm'].values
    mean = np.nanmean(x)
    std = np.nanstd(x)
    xs = kdeline.get_xdata()
    ys = kdeline.get_ydata()
    prev_height = 0 if np.isscalar(prev_ys) else np.interp(mean, xs, prev_ys)
    height = np.interp(mean, xs, ys)
    ax.vlines(mean, prev_height, height, color=kdeline.get_color(), ls=':')
    ax.fill_between(xs, prev_ys, ys, facecolor=kdeline.get_color(), alpha=0.2)
    # filter the region where x within one standard deviation of the mean
    sd_filter = (xs >= mean - std) & (xs <= mean + std)
    # show this region with a darker color
    ax.fill_between(xs[sd_filter], 0 if np.isscalar(prev_ys) else prev_ys[sd_filter], ys[sd_filter],
                    facecolor=kdeline.get_color(), alpha=0.2)
    prev_ys = ys

plt.show()



Thank you JohanC the only challenge I have now is how to display the quartiles range.

Please clarify. Usually, the mean is combined with the standard deviation, not the quartiles.  Usually, the quartiles are combined with the median, not the mean.  Anyway, you can use the same functions as in the other example code.

Thank you JohanC for the correction. I should have been referring to the standard deviation.

I updated the code to also visualize the standard deviation.

I have used code JohanC provided it works well.
I have attempted to add a region to show the standard deviation, but my attempt is not elegant.
Is there a way to make this code better, perhaps by dropping the "stacked" design so the entire plot region of the each of the species data would touch the x axis even in sections of the x-axis where the regions may overlap.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import seaborn as sns;
import numpy as np;

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins');
fig, ax_02 = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(12, 4))
if 1==1:
    ax = sns.kdeplot(data=penguins, x='flipper_length_mm', hue='species', multiple='stack', fill=False, ax=ax_02);
    
    prev_ys = 0;
    left_sdev_prev_ys=0;
    right_sdev_prev_ys=0;
    for kdeline, legend_text in zip(ax.lines, ax.legend_.texts[::-1]):
        print(legend_text.get_text());
        species_str: str=legend_text.get_text();
        x = penguins[penguins['species'] == legend_text.get_text()]['flipper_length_mm'].values;
        mean = np.nanmean(x);
        my_mean = np.nanmean(x);
        my_sdev = np.nanstd(x);
        xs = kdeline.get_xdata();
        ys = kdeline.get_ydata();
        prev_height = 0 if np.isscalar(prev_ys) else np.interp(my_mean, xs, prev_ys);
        height = np.interp(my_mean, xs, ys);
        ax.vlines(my_mean, prev_height, height, color=kdeline.get_color(), ls=':');
        ax.fill_between(xs, prev_ys, ys, facecolor=kdeline.get_color(), alpha=0.2);

        left_sdev_height = np.interp(my_mean-my_sdev, xs, ys);
        left_sdev_prev_height = 0 if np.isscalar(left_sdev_prev_ys) else np.interp(my_mean-my_sdev, xs, left_sdev_prev_ys);
        ax.vlines(my_mean-my_sdev, left_sdev_prev_height, left_sdev_height, color=kdeline.get_color(), ls=':');
        left_sdev_prev_ys=ys;
        
        right_sdev_height = np.interp(my_mean+my_sdev, xs, ys);
        right_sdev_prev_height = 0 if np.isscalar(right_sdev_prev_ys) else np.interp(my_mean+my_sdev, xs, right_sdev_prev_ys);
        ax.vlines(my_mean+my_sdev, right_sdev_prev_height, right_sdev_height, color=kdeline.get_color(), ls=':');
        right_sdev_prev_ys=ys;
        ax.fill_between(xs, 0, ys, where=(my_mean-my_sdev <= xs) & (xs <= my_mean+my_sdev), interpolate=True, facecolor=kdeline.get_color(), alpha=0.2)

        prev_ys = ys;
    
    plt.show();

